# (Domino Notes)The object variable not set

Tags: button, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have an action button on Notes Document.

After I click the button, will show an error message. How can I solve this problem?

The following is the error message and the code :

[ERROR MESSAGE]

Object variable not set.

[CODE]

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uipr As NotesUIDocument
    Set uipr = ws.CurrentDocument
    If username(0) <> uipr.fieldgettext("PUR_DEPT_S01") And username(0) <> "SYSADMIN" Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim myflag As Variant
        myflag = False
        For i = 0 To Ubound(userrole)
            If userrole(i) = "[DO_ALL_ACTION]" Then
                myflag = True
            End If
        Next            
        If myflag = False Then
            Messagebox "ERROR"
            Exit Sub
        End If 
    End If
    
    If  uipr.fieldgettext("PR_STATUS") <> "purchasing" Then
        Messagebox "PLEASE CHECK THE STATUS"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim askme As Variant
        askme = ws.Prompt(PROMPT_YESNO, "CLOSE", "Sure to return the division？", "", "")    
        If askme = False Then Exit Sub
        If uipr.EditMode = False Then uipr.EditMode = True
    End If
    Call ChangeField
    Msgbox "Change OK"
    uipr.Save
    uipr.Close
End Sub
Sub ChangeField
    Dim DayNum As Integer
    DayNum=ComputeDayDiff(uipr.fieldgettext("REF_DATE"),TW_sys_date)
    Call uipr.fieldsettext("PR_STATUS","Divsion")
    Call uipr.fieldsettext("NEXT_PERSON","Division")
    Call uipr.fieldsettext("PUR_DEPT_S01","")
    Call uipr.fieldsettext("TPAY_DEPT_S01","")
    Call uipr.fieldsettext("BUYER","")
End Sub
```

Comment: Try the Script Debugger as well: Tools/Debug Lotusscript. And +1 for Torsten's reply, it will definitely help you in the long run. For now: where and how is username declared?

Comment: Your code never sets username(0) or userrole(i), so it is obviously not the complete code. Nobody can possibly tell you what the problem is without seeing all the relevant code.

Answer (score 5):

You solve EVERY problem in LotusScript (and a lot of other programming languages as well) by adding an ERROR HANDLER.

The first line and the last lines of **EVERY** sub and function should be something like:

```
'- Very first error line
On Error Goto ErrorHandler

...YOUR CODE GOES HERE...

EndOfRoutine:
  Exit Sub 'or Exit Function or Exit Property, depending on where you are
ErrorHandler:
'- print error message in status bar or log.nsf on server
  Print Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl & " in procedure " & GetThreadInfo( LSI_THREAD_PROC )
' or show it to user
  MsgBox Err & ", " & Error & " in line " & Erl & " in procedure " & GetThreadInfo( LSI_THREAD_PROC )
  Resume EndOfRoutine
```

Whenever you run your code now, it will EXACTLY tell you in which line the error occurs. From there you can probably deduct which Object Variable is not set. That error typically means, that a variable (typically of one of the NotesXXX- classes) is not assigned a value.

I won't read through your code to guess which variable it might be. Add error handling and find out yourself, so that you are not helpless the next time an error occurs.

And here is the broken record again (I write it over and over again):
**NEVER write a single line of code without error handler.**

Answer (score 0):

You are never declaring *username*, as both Richard and D.Bugger already mentioned. I am pretty sure that is where you get the error. You are also using *uipr* in the subroutine *ChangeField()*, but you never pass the object into the function.

But like Torsten says, use the debugger, that will help you.

I wrote a series of blog posts several years ago about how to write better Lotusscript code. You can find them at http://blog.texasswede.com/how-to-write-better-code-in-notesdomino/  It's too long to paste all of them in here, but below is the part about variable names.

> It is not hard to write easy to read Lotusscript code. Just follow
> some simple rules. As always, there are more than one way to do
> things, but this is how I do it (most of the time). I found that this
> works for me.
>
> **Variables**
>
> Always use Option Declare (or Option Explicit) in all your code. This
> will prevent you from getting errors later when (not if!) you spell a
> variable wrong. Option Declare forces you to declare all variables
> before you use them. It also helps you by warning if a function or
> method is called with a variable of the wrong data type. Most of your
> bugs can be avoided using Option Declare. Use it!
>
> Give your variables meaningful names. There is no need to abbreviate
> variables and/or give them cryptical names, or  you will just spell
> them wrong later. Use a naming system that makes sense to you. As I
> mentioned in my previous post, I avoid Hungarian notation, it just
> makes the variables hard to read. Since Lotusscript is a strongly
> typed language, the compiler is taking care of data types. I however
> do use some indicators for certain variables. For the few global
> variables I use, I do prefix them with g_, as I then can give local
> variables a similar name. By giving your variables meaningful names,
> the code also becomes largely self-documenting.
>
> Be consistent in how you capitalize your variables. I normally write
> all variables in lower case only, but that is my personal preference.
> That way they are easy to distinguish from built-in Lotusscript
> functions and properties of objects. Some programmers prefer some
> version of CamelCase, which is fine. I occasionally use that,
> especially in Javascript.
>
> Be consistent in how you name related variables. If you have a
> variable named startpos to indicate the beginning position of a string
> within another string, name the other variable endpos, not posend.
> Think through all variables you need so you give them good names. The
> variables posstart and posend are not as easy to read and understand
> as startpos and endpos. Of course, using camelCase, posStart and
> posEnd are much easier to decypher. Use the same/similar naming
> convention for the Domino objects as IBM uses in the online help. Use
> ws, uidoc, session, db, doc, etc. If you need more than one object of
> any type, e.g. NotesDatabase, name them in a consistent way. I always
> use thisdb for the database the code is executing in, nabdb for
> names.nsf, archivedb for (you guessed it!) an archive database, etc.
>
> Declare the variables at the beginning of the
> code/subroutine/function. Don’t declare them throughout the code, this
> makes it much harder to find them later, when you perhaps need to see
> what data type they are.
>
> Declare the variables in a logical order. I always group the variables
> by type. First the UI classes, then backend classes, then any custom
> classes/data types, and finally other variables. Within each group, I
> declare them in the order I am using them. The benefit of this is that
> you get an idea of where to look for the variables in your
> function/subroutine.
>
> Use Option Declare. Yes, this needs to be repeated. Way too many
> (especially new) programmers forget this, or don’t know about this.